# Setting up NSMutableArray - Can someone explain what this code snippet does?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've found this snippet of code on the net. It sets up an NSMutableArray in a way I've not seen before ( I'm an Obj-C newb). Can someone explain what it's doing and why you would do it this way? Particularly the @syncronized, static and little plus sign on the method signature.

```
add the following to the .h file:
+(NSMutableArray *)allMySprites;

add the following to he .m file after implementation:

static NSMutableArray * allMySprites = nil;

+(NSMutableArray *)allMySprites {
    @synchronized(allMySprites) {
        if (allMySprites == nil)
            allMySprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return allMySprites;
    }
 return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to the other responses ... the posted code is wrong. It should be more like this:

```
@implementation SpriteManager
+ (NSMutableArray*) allMySprites {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (allMySprites == nil) {
            allMySprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return allMySprites;
}
@end
```

It makes no sense to @synchronize on nil. Using self in a class method refers to the class and not the instance. Also the 'return nil' in the original code is pointless.

A better approach where the @synchronized can be completely avoided is to use a class initializer method:

```
@implementation SomeClass
+ (void) initialize
{
    allMySprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
@end
```

The initialize methods are guaranteed to be called before the class is used.

Comment: +initialize can be called more than once if you have subclasses. It’s best to check that you’re actually initializing your class like so:

        if (self == [SpriteManager class]) {
            allMySprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

Answer (score 1):

The `+` sign indicates the method is `static` as opposed to `instance` methods. It means the method belongs to the class rather than each instance of a class (just like [`static` things in Java and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-java/413904#413904)). `@synchronized` acquires a lock on the object specified ([like `lock` statement in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx)). It means no other thread can enter a `@synchronized` block with that object.

The code as a whole is trying to initialize a singleton collection the first time (when it's not initialized yet) and cache it for use in subsequent calls to that method. The synchronized block creates a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) to make the initialization part safe in case of a race condition where two threads try to get the value roughly the same time while it's still doing the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation of the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), basically a way of making sure that you only have one copy of your `MySprites`.

The details:

- The `+` means that this is a class method
- The `@syncyronize` makes access to the `allMySprites` variable thread-safe (there are a few caveats but that's the one line summary)
- I believe that the `static` limits the scope of the variable only to the file